# Crystal activex report viewer with linq

Tags: vb.net, linq

I want to used crystal reports activex viewer with linq.

```
Dim crxApp As New CRAXDDRT.Application
Dim crxReport As New CRAXDDRT.Report

crxReport = crxApp.OpenReport(Application.StartupPath & "/Report/Report_Daily.rpt", Nothing)

dim query = From obj_tbl In dbModelAdmin.v_InvoiceReturnings Where obj_tbl.InvoiceId = 2
                      Select obj_tbl

crxReport.Database.SetDataSource(query)
rptDaily.ReportSource = crxReport
rptDaily.ViewReport()
```

When I run I got the all data but what I want is to get the data by condition as in query.

Comment: What type of object is `dbModelAdmin.v_InvoiceReturnings`? Are you getting any error with your LINQ statement? You really don't need the Select part of that query.